# Cuál sería el similar a rellenar un RecyclerView con un Adapter en Swift

Tags: android, swift

Ahora que estoy terminando de programar mi app en Android estoy buscando la forma de replicarla en Swift para IOS, sin embargo, las herramientas que use en Android no tienen el mismo nombre en Swift y creo que no hacen lo mismo...

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cuál herramienta se podría parecer a rellenar un RecyclerView con un Adapter y que además al clickear cada objeto en el RecyclerView me redirija a distintos sitios?

Espero puedan ayudarme,
desde ya,
muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hola si queres hacer una lista en iOS podes usar el UITableView podriamos decir que funciona como el RecyclerView y las veces de Adapter las hara la clase en la cual implementes el UITableViewDataSource y/o el UITableViewDelegate que son interfaces que deben ser implementadas para hacer funcionar el UITableView.